# Got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk1' issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am getting an error, that I do not know how to fix and even why I am getting that error.

I am rendering a form to link a team to a project in a url where like : 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/project/20/linkteam2 where 20 is my pk1 = 20 which is the project id. I am using pk1 and pk2 because when the team is linked, the url become : http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/project/20/team_id

For some reason I am getting:

```
TypeError at /website/project/21/linkteam2/
TeamSelect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk1'
```

my code is :

```
def TeamSelect(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            data = select_form.cleaned_data['team_choice']
            obj2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin=request.user)
            obj3 = obj2.latest('id')
            if obj3.team_id == None:
                obj3.team_id = data
                obj3.save()
                obj4 = obj3.team_id
                obj5 = obj4.members.all()

                for i in obj5:
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': i.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = i.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'test')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1':obj3.id, 'pk2':obj4}))
            else:
                print('this project has already a team')
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')

    else:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })
```

my html:

```
{% load static %}
<div class="invite-team">
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
    <div class="jumbo-text">
      <h7>Your project has been created, It is time to link a team or create a new for your project</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="jumbo-button">
        <a href="{% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
        <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>   Create a new team</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

myUrl:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from website import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hr_index/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='hr_index'),
    url(r'^candidate_index/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(),name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^employee_index/$', views.EmployeeIndex.as_view(),name='employee_index'),
    url(r'^addproject/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='add_project'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/addteam/$', views.TeamCreate.as_view(), name='add_team'),
    #url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam/$', views.LinkTeam.as_view(), name='link_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$', views.TeamSelect, name='team_select'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data2/$',views.TeamChartData.as_view(), name='TeamChartData'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$',views.EmployeeChartData.as_view(), name='EmployeeChartData'),
    #url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view(), name='chartdata'),
```

]

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unexpected because you do not define the argument in the view. All your view is expecting is the request. Change

```
def TeamSelect(request):
```

to

```
def TeamSelect(request, pk1=None):
```

to add extra arguments to the view.

Comment: could you explain why None ? and not the value of pk1 ?

Comment: because in URL you are sending `(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)`.

Comment: The =None part is to do with the way python deals with default values. Using a placeholder like None is done to avoid certain unintended behaviours, though it can have its uses. See for example http://www.effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm